# Pass multi-line data to pipe in Makefile

Tags: pipe, makefile

In bash file, I can write this:

```
my_program << EOF
Some test
More test
A lot of multi-line text
EOF
```

This will launch my_program executable and pass three lines of text (or more) to it through a pipe.

Now I want to so same in Makefile (GNU make). I've found no standard solution and it's solved like this:

```
LaunchMyProgram:
    echo -en "Some test\\nMore test\\nA lot of multi-line text\\n" | my_program
```

But this look very ugly. Is there more fine solution?

Comment: I'm not sure about site this question should be at. Maybe it's place is on stackoverflow or superuser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is ugly, but there’s not much you can do about it. `make` executes each line as its own shell script, unless the line ends with a `\` continuation character; but then the newline is stripped. This is a little bit cleaner:

```
all:
    printf 'hi\n\
    there\n\
    how\n\
    are\n\
    you'
```

Normally I’d use `echo` here but `printf` is a bit more portable when it comes to handling escape characters.

Comment: In my case it is displaying ```\``` at the end of each echoed line which causes the script to fail.

Comment: @MaciejZałucki I’ve updated the answer with something a bit more portable. If it’s still not working for you, can you provide a few more details on your OS, make, and shell versions?

Comment: In my case it was GNU Make 4.2.1 on Ubuntu 20. Using ```'``` was including everything in the text so it resulted with duplicated endlines and ```\``` at the end of every second line. After removing ```\n``` it still had new lines (but not duplicated) with ```\```. Removing ```\``` did not work as make did not interpret it as a single command anymore. Seems as if it is some feature. It works fine if I use ```"```, this way newlines and ```\``` are not included in the text. Is that some kind of feature I'm not aware of?

Comment: @MaciejZałucki Ok, I see the problem on Ubuntu. I’d only tested this on my mac which has older versions of make; and something must have changed in Make. I’ll have to update this again later.